# Wanting to add a reaction whenever a message is sent (Using Hikari + Lightbulb)

Tags: python, discord

I'm using Hikari + Lightbulb to create my first discord bot and I'm using this as an opportunity to learn as much as possible. As mentioned in the title, I just want to learn how to use
`add_reaction(":smile:")` correctly. I've read through the Hikari documentation and to be honest, I am having difficulties understanding it fully. I thought the correct line of code would be something along the lines of this

```
@bot.listen(hikari.MessageCreateEvent)
async def message(event):
    print(event.content)
    await message.add_reaction(":smile:")
```

When I go to run this code I receive the following error: `AttributeError: 'GuildMessageCreateEvent' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'`. This is making think my error lies with using the `MessageCreateEvent` object but after reading the documentation I can't tell which object *does* support this attribute. Is there something I'm missing? Or am I simply not using the attribute correctly and it's meant to be used in some other way?

Comment: What is the `message` variable here? You are only receiving the event so you want to do `event.message.add_reaction(":smile:")`.

Comment: Interesting, that's definitely put me a step in the right direction so thank you. I'm now getting the error `emoji_id: - Value "" is not snowflake.` 

Time to have a look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I've managed to figure it out with Help from the comments (Thank you Guimoute).

I needed to include `event.` before the `message.add_reaction`.

Just in case anyone has had a similar issue this is the complete code that worked for me

```
@bot.listen(hikari.MessageCreateEvent)
async def message(event):
    print(event.content)
    await event.message.add_reaction(emoji="")
```

Keen eyed among you will notice I had to change the end. If you don't be specific and and use `emoji=""` is will tell you that the value is not snowflake, I don't fully understand it but reading over some of the discord dev portal documentation, I think it's a requirement of discord.